# Screen Capture in PNG Format Works, but not BMP Format

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx

I'm using the code below to capture the screen with a game running

```
public static Bitmap CaptureScreen()
{
    DxScreenCapture cap = new DxScreenCapture();
    var surface = cap.CaptureScreen();

    Bitmap png;
    using (DataStream stream = Surface.ToStream(surface, ImageFileFormat.Bmp))
    {
        png = new Bitmap(stream);
        png.Save(@"C:\Temp\MyFile.bmp");
    }

    return png;
}
```

When saving as `ImageFileFormat.Bmp`, the saved file is entirely black.  If I change the format to `ImageFileFormat.Png` (and the file extension to .png), the image saves just fine.

Why can I save in PNG format, but not in BMP format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work (see the [complete enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
png.Save(@"C:\Temp\MyFile.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

Comment: Strange, just specifying ImageFormat.Bmp does cause it to save correctly.  I naively thought that it would be interpreted correctly from the DataStream (as it was in the case of a PNG).  With this working, a following line `Bitmap rgn = png.Clone(new Rectangle(911, 170, 32, 14), png.PixelFormat)` is throwing an OutOfMemoryException.  The specified region is cearly inside `png`'s bounds.  Any thoughts?